# SQL Site Map Provider Review

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need display navigation in my website with ASP.NET 4 components.

Navigation use XmlSiteMapProvider and file hierarchy as XML file.

Because my website is a CMS I am looking for a solution able to store hierarchy in DataBase or in some sort of Business Logic.

I found out SQL Site Map Provider, which seems a workaround to store hierarchy in SQL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx

My questions:
- I would like to know your opinion on it.
- If you know some other alternative solutions.

Thanks guys for your help and time

Bye

Comment: That is **THE** solution for your problem. I don't know of any useful alternatives other than writing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The article you mention is one to which I pointed out on quite some occasions over at forums.asp.net. The members there trying to implement it were content with the workings of it.

Personally I don't know about an alternative but the source code can be downloaded and if needed altered as per your likings.